# java design pattern for enforcing a class prerrequisite

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am wondering what is the best design for a class-wide prerrequisite be enforced at construction time.

Let me put a simplified example.

I have a class representing a secure string, for example a Password. Passwords are only stored as their hash representation. Passwords cannot be inspected, but only checked against an attempted value.

```
class Password {
  private String passwordHash;
  private Password(){};
  public Password(String aPassword) {
    setPassword(aPassword);
  }
  public void setPassword(String aPassword) {
     passwordHash = hash(aPassword); 
  }
  public boolean checkPassword(String attempt) {
     return verify(attempt, passwordHash);
  }
}
```

The question is how to design the selection of the hashing algorithm. The client code must be able to choose from different hash algorithms. And, in a given application all passwords must use the same hash algorithm.

So, I define a Hasher interface,

```
interface Hasher {
  String hash(String password);
  boolean verify(String attempt, String hash);
}
```

There might be different Hasher implementations.

```
class SimpleHasher implements Hasher {
  public String hash(String password) {  // native java String.hashCode()  
    return Integer.toString(password.hashCode(),16);
  }
  public boolean verify(String attempt, String hash) {
    return attempt.hashCode()==Integer.valueOf(hash, 16);
  }  
}

class SecureHasher implements Hasher {
  public String hash(String password) {  // Secure SCrypt hash
    return com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil.scrypt(password,16384,8,1);
  }
  public boolean verify(String attempt, String hash) {
    return com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil.check(attempt,hash);
  }
}
```

The client code must choose an implementation and set the hasher. Until then, no one can instantiate a Password. And once set, the hasher cannot be changed.

Here is the design decision.

Currently, I declare a `static private` variable, so the hasher is the same for all Password instances; and a setter that enforces that it cannot be changed once is set.

```
class Password {
  static private Hasher hasher = null;
  static public void setHasher(Hasher ahasher) throws Exception {
    if (hasher!=null) throw new Exception("hasher cannot be changed");
    hasher = ahasher;
  } 
  ....
```

and the constructor ensures that hasher is set

```
class Password {
   ...    
   public Password(String aPassword) throws Exception {
     if (hasher==null) throw new Exception("no hasher set yet");  
     setPassword(aPassword);
   } 
   ...
```

so far, so good. But, in my opinion, it doesn't look quite nice. I wonder if there is some common pattern to solve this problem. So my question is if such a pattern exists and how it can be implemented in my case.

Comment: Would you be open to using OAuth2?

Comment: that's not the point, I use Password and Hasher as a simplified example. My question is about designing a classwide prerrequisite.

Comment: In general your use case sounds similar to the Strategy Pattern.  I don't like your implementation because static global variables lead to errors and difficulties on their own, and are hard to test.  I think I would just allow that different objects using different strategies are going to be not equal or fail.  I think I would use a Factory Pattern that took a parameter for the type of password hashing desired, thus *allowing* programmers to chose their hashing strategy, but not *enforce* it.

Comment: I don't like it neither, that's why my question. But I want to enforce a single strategy, and not require all clients create their own, just once and for all.

Comment: it still would be 1 for all, the fact that it *may* be different implementations does not mean that it have to. What you want is a shared state between different objects of the same class. Shared state is not cool. So, just make your `Hasher` a field (non-static), create its instance in client code (only 1 time) and pass this instance in constructor when you create instances of `Password`.

Comment: Well that's the point in my requirements. I want to enforce a common algorithm for all my instances, and I want to avoid passing Hasher instances to each constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your design and try to approach it a little differently.
First of, do some refactoring. Constructor should not contain any code. Secondly, it is great that you make interface of a hasher. Nevertheless, I would refactor it to:

```
public interface Hash {
    String hashed(String value);
    boolean isValid(String hashed);
}
```

Next, change your Password class:

```
public class Password {

    private String password;
    private Hash hash;

    public Password(String password, Hash hash) {
        this.password = password;
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    public boolean isValid(String password) {
       return hash.hashed(this.password).equals(hash.hashed(password);
    }
}
```

That would be an elegant design. You just need to make sure that proper hash implementation is passed through the constructor. Once that is set, 
every password will validated be the same implementation.

Comment: in your solution there is no sense to keep `password` as a field of `class Password`. Also I would remove explicit call to `hashed()` method, and incapsulate this call to `isValid()` because it seems like the hashed value is used only for comparison and that's it

Comment: and as I understood, the question is exactly about eliminating the passing of explicit `Hasher` to each instance of `Password`

Comment: I edited my answer now. Password encapsulated raw password and only when isValid method is called it hashed itself and to check password comparing it accordingly. I know that question was how to eliminate passing instance of Hash to each instance of Password, but I think that it is a bad a idea. That is why I propose an alternative design.

Comment: Although I can see that your design might be a more elegant way to model the hash, it doesn't address my issue about how to enforce prerequisites in a constructor, so I don't think that it answers my question.